# Pusher subscription error. Laravel

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm trying to make a chat between two persons in Laravel 5.4 with Pusher.

First, I send an Ajax post request:

```
$('#btn-chat').click(function (){
    $.post('sendMessage',{
        _token: $("[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'),
        user_id: userId,
        chat_id: 1,
        message: $('#btn-input').val()
    },
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Then, a controller takes the request:

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $message = new Message;
    $message->fill($request->all());
    $message->message = $request->message;
    $message->save();
    broadcast(new MessageSent($message))->toOthers();
    return 'Return MessageController';
}
```

Also, here is my MessageSent event:

```
class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    public function __construct($message) {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastOn() {
        return new PrivateChannel('chat.'.$this->message->chat_id);
    }
}
```

And my channels.php document:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('chat.*', function ($user, $chat_id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $chat_id;
});
```

And finally, the JavaScript listens to events:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('pusher_key', {
    cluster: 'us2',
    encrypted: true,
    authEndpoint: 'broadcasting/auth',
    auth: {
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $("[name='csrf-token']").attr('content')
        }
    }
});
Pusher.logToConsole = true;
var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-chat.1');
channel.bind('MessageSent', (data) => {
  alert(data.message);
});
```

All that should to the work, but when I load the chat page, it throws an error on JavaScript console:

```
Pusher : No callbacks on private-chat.1 for pusher:subscription_error
```

Comment: My question is solved. I had this problem for at least one day, and before posting this question, I tried to solve it by myself. Let me explain my solution as soon as I can, soryy.

Answer (score 0):

Pusher emits events automatically in certain circumstances.

`Pusher : No callbacks on private-chat.1 for pusher:subscription_error`

Is telling you that there was an error subscribing to the channel, but you haven't bound a callback to that event. You should be able to get more information about the error you experienced during subscription by binding to the `subscription:error` event. You can find more info [here](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#subscription_error).

Answer (score 0):

As leesio anwsered, Pusher emits events if an error ocurrs.

Afther I added:

```
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

It displayed in console:

```
JSON returned from webapp was invalid, yet status code was 200.
```

Because the Laravel broadcasting routes (broadcasting/auth) returned an HTTP response, not the JSON that Pusher needs.
So my solution was create a new route (pusherAuth), and then returning to Pusher the following JSON:

```
public function pusherAuth(Request $request){
    $key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $channel_name = $request->channel_name;
    $socket_id = $request->socket_id;
    $string_to_sign = $socket_id.':'.$channel_name;
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, $secret);
    return response()->json(['auth' => $key.':'.$signature]);
}
```

Client-side JavaScript:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
    cluster: 'us2',
    encrypted: true,
    authEndpoint: 'pusherAuth', //Before 'broadcasting/auth'
    auth: {
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $("[name='csrf-token']").attr('content')
        }
    }
});
```

And that should do the work. I don't know why I couldn't do it with Laravel broadcasting routes, but I post this answer if anyone has the same problem.

More info:

- [Pusher auth signatures](https://pusher.com/docs/auth_signatures)
- [PHP HMAC SHA56](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#php)